# Google Cloud Build pipeline in Mono-repository architecture with single cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

We are using multiple python deployments into a single GitHub repository with a folder structure. Each directory contains a separate scripts module.

```
service-1/
     deployment-1/
        app/
        Dockerfile
        cloudbuild.yaml
     deployment-2/
        app/
        Dockerfile
        cloudbuild.yaml
service-2/
     deployment-1/
        app/
        Dockerfile
        cloudbuild.yaml
service-3/
     deployment-1/
        app/
        Dockerfile
        cloudbuild.yaml
     deployment-2/
        app/
        Dockerfile
        cloudbuild.yaml
.gitignore
README.md
requirements.txt
```

where deployment-1 will work as a single deployment and deployment-2 as another deployment for each service.

We are planning to manage a single trigger in a pipeline that triggers the build only for the deployment where the latest commit is found.

If anyone can please provide suggestions on how to keep single YAML files & build it better way using the cloud build. So that we don't require to manage multiple triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, nothing is magic!! The dispatch is either done by configuration (multiple trigger) or by code.

If you want to avoid multiple trigger, you need to code the dispatch:

- Detect the code that have change in GIT (could be several service in the same time)
- Iterate over the updated folders and run a Cloud Build (so, a new one) for each of them

It's small piece of shell code. Not so difficult but you have to maintain/test/debug it. Is it easier that multiple trigger? It's up to you, according to your team skills in devops area.